# How to scrap data in a text that has nested tags?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a dictionary website and want to get the English translation of a word. I am using `soup.find_all()` to find the second instance of a tag in the page source. But the function is returning a long object because the tags are nested:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'ToWrd'})[1]
```

It returns:

```
<td class="ToWrd">pupil <em class="tooltip POS2">n<span><i>noun</i>: Refers to person, place, thing, quality, etc.</span></em></td>
```

But I am just interested in "pupil" which is the meaning of the word that I am searching in that dictionary website. Can anyone help how to extract this just this word?

Please, note that I don't want to use a numpy or pandas function because the code does not have these dependencies and I don't want to add them. For example, I am not looking for this solution:

```
pd.DataFrame(soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'ToWrd'})[1])[0][0]
```

which returns:

```
'pupil '
```

Comment: what website are you querying?

Comment: You should be able to do `td = soup.find_all(...)` then `word = td.text.split()[0]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different approaches to get your goal - simplest is mentioned by @Tim Roberts - But be aware that it will just work if there is a single word:

```
soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'ToWrd'})[1].text.split()[0]
```

An alternative, working with single / compound nouns / multiple words is `stripped_strings`:

```
list(soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'ToWrd'})[1].stripped_strings)[0]
```

Same job will also be done by combine `get_text()` with parameters and `split()`, but I prefer `stripped_strings`:

```
soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'ToWrd'})[1].get_text('|',strip=True).split('|')[0]
```

**Note:** *If there is only one `<td>` with that class use `find()` instead of `find_all()`*

#### Example

Will extract single as well as compound nouns / multiple words:

```
html = '''
<td class="ToWrd">pupil<em class="tooltip POS2">n<span><i>noun</i>: Refers to person, place, thing, quality, etc.</span></em></td>
<td class="ToWrd">ice cream<em class="tooltip POS2">n<span><i>noun</i>: Refers to person, place, thing, quality, etc.</span></em></td>
'''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

[list(w.stripped_strings)[0] for w in soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'ToWrd'})]
```

#### Output

```
['pupil', 'ice cream']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regex:

```
import re

valid = re.compile(r'<td class="ToWrd">(\w+) <em class="tooltip POS2">')
print(valid.match('<td class="ToWrd">pupil <em class="tooltip POS2">n<span><i>noun</i>: Refers to person, place, thing, quality, etc.</span></em></td>').group(1))
```

returns

```
pupil
```

Example above works only if all tags have

```
<td class="ToWrd">
```

before and

```
<em class="tooltip POS2">
```

after your wanted word though. But you might adjust the regex accordingly.

Comment: Thank you SimonH. This is a great solution, I applied it for the word "pupil" it worked but when I applied it for "ice cream" it didn't work.      For example compare these to inks: r = requests.get('https://www.wordreference.com/fren/%C3%A9l%C3%A8ve') and 
r = requests.get('https://www.wordreference.com/fren/cr%C3%A8me%20glac%C3%A9e'). The code is:
aa = str(soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'ToWrd'})[1])
valid = re.compile(r'<td class="ToWrd">(\w+) <em class="tooltip POS2">')
print(valid.match(aa).group(1))`

Comment: @SaeedAmirA.. Oh yeah right, if white spaces should be matched too, you can adjust the regex to be: `valid = re.compile(r'<td class="ToWrd">([\w\s]+)<em class="tooltip POS2">')`

Comment: Or if you want to capture absolutely everything between those two tags just use `.+`, e.g. `valid = re.compile(r'<td class="ToWrd">(.+) <em class="tooltip POS2">')`